# How do I remove .html from my website URL and make it work in local host (VS Code Live Server)

Tags: html, liveserver

The locally hosted website run with visual studio code extension does not allow me to visit the subpages

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I have this code written in the settings.json file

settings.json

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai Night",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    },
    "liveServer.settings.rewriterules": {
        "^/learn$": "/learn.html"
    }
}
```

I am trying to remove the .html from my website. I have a .htaccess with code written in it. On the actual website, it works and the .html is removed but on my local hosted website, it shows "Cannot GET /learn"

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment out this line or remove it from **settings.json**

```
"liveServer.settings.rewriterules": {
        "^/learn$": "/learn.html"
}
```

then restart vscode and try

Comment: I removed that code but I still get "Cannot GET /learn"

I asked chat GPT and it said to put. In the settings,json file, the color is faded so I'm assuming its not valid

Comment: @AndrewNguyenAI don't trust chatgpt